# Did Netanyahu say (apparently in 2001) "I actually stopped the Oslo Accords"?

Tags: politics, quotes, israel, benjamin-netanyahu

There are a few sources claiming he said this ("I actually stopped the [Oslo Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords)"), but all of those I found are rather left-wing. E.g. a 2012 [opinion piece](https://www.haaretz.com/opinion/2012-05-07/ty-article/netanyahus-presidents/0000017f-ebf4-dc91-a17f-fffd28f20000) in [Haaretz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haaretz) or a [piece](https://jewishcurrents.org/drawing-a-red-line-around-netanyahu) in [Jewish Currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Currents) from the same year. To quote the latter:

> Benjamin Netanyahu is a man who boasted on videotape, in 2001, “I actually stopped the Oslo Accords.”

So, did he actually say that?

I'm a bit skeptical because it's apparently not been more widely reported, although maybe it was just considered a politically unremarkable statement, I'm not sure. Netanyahu did formally negotiate the [Wye River Memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wye_River_Memorandum), which Wikipedia describes as "aimed to resume the implementation of the 1995 Interim Agreement on the West Bank and the Gaza Strip (Oslo II Accord)". So him boasting about stopping the accords is perhaps not entirely congruent with that... Or maybe it is, given the word "resume"?!

Answer (score 35):

Yes, he did say it.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/uIHZ_CPJECU?si=x2ZqHyoU5zL2XFO1), uploaded in 2011, he is seen talking to a kid in his home and claiming that he stopped the Oslo accords by interpreting the wording in a way favorable to Israel (with American backing). At the very end he said

> כי מאותו הרגע עצרתי למעשה את הסכמי אוסלו

> Because from that moment onwards I actually stopped the Oslo Accords

The video itself doesn't have context, but it can be found in this [Hebrew article](https://www.haaretz.co.il/opinions/2010-07-15/ty-article/0000017f-defe-db22-a17f-feff8bcf0000) by Gideon Levi where he tells us that it is a recording made in secret of Netanyahu, as a private citizen, visiting the home of a bereaved family in Ofra in 2001.

It should be noted that despite his boasting, he did sign and execute the [Hebron agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Concerning_the_Redeployment_in_Hebron) (which he mentions in the video) and then signed and partially executed the [Wye river agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wye_River_Memorandum), all part of the Oslo accords, and in all Israel withdrew from Territory. Netanyahu himself would come to regret the Hebron agreement and [call it a mistake](https://www.haaretz.co.il/misc/2001-07-16/ty-article/0000017f-e8c4-da9b-a1ff-ecefc6480000).

Comment: I see. So "explaining to a kid" might be part of why he put it in those simple terms.

Comment: @Fizz that's your interpretation. It's the same person that now claims he was against the withdrawal from Gaza even though he voted in favor of it in all the votes that mettered and was the treasury minister up to 8 days before it started, meaning he effectively was the one who financed it.

Answer (score 13):

I found what you've quoted [here](https://electronicintifada.net/content/video-netanyahu-brags-he-deceived-us-destroy-oslo-accords/8934), [here](https://www.redressonline.com/2010/07/netanyahu-i-deceived-us-to-destroy-oslo-accords/) and [here](https://www.palestinechronicle.com/netanyahu-i-deceived-us-to-destroy-oslo-accords/):

> The “trick” that stopped further withdrawals, Mr Netanyahu adds, was to redefine what parts of the occupied territories counted as a “specified military site” under the Oslo accords. He wanted the White House to approve in writing the classification of the Jordan Valley, a large area of the West Bank, as such a military site.
>
> “Now, they did not want to give me that letter, so I did not give [them] the Hebron Agreement. I stopped the government meeting, I said: ‘I’m not signing.’ Only when the letter came … did I sign the Hebron Agreement. Why does this matter? Because at that moment I actually stopped the Oslo accords.”

They all refer to [this Hebrew video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBFihtGYFSg) of Netanyahu in 2001 (The YouTube channel of Jewish Currents). The caption of the video reads:

> מתיישבים צילמו את ביבי ללא ידיעתו מדבר חופשי על ככה שמ שהערבים באמת רוצים זה לחסל את כל היהודים, שהסכמי אוסלו הם אסון, שהוא הצליח להפסיק את הסכמי אוסלו על ידי הכללת שטחים צבאיים כשטחי ישראל בהם בקעת הירדן ושהוא היה חייב לתת את חברון כי עדיף לתת 2% אחוזים מאשר 100%.

Google translates it as:

> Settlers filmed Bibi without his knowledge talking freely about how the Arabs really want to eliminate all the Jews, that the Oslo Accords are a disaster, that he managed to stop the Oslo Accords by including military territories as Israeli territories including the Jordan Valley, and that he had to give Hebron because it is better to give 2% percent than 100%.

Comment: I see those 3 fist links are all a copy of a piece by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Cook that originally is said to have appeared in the UAE's _The National_.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that.